# cv2.approxPolyDP() , cv2.arcLength() How these works

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, data-science, image-manipulation

How do these function works? I am using Python3.7 and OpenCv 4.2.0. Thanks in Advance.

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please read the documentation and do some research before asking questions on this forum

Comment: Thanks sir. @MihailDuchev
If you don't mind please recommend some source of learning.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for a example snippet, below is one:

```
import cv2
import imutils

# edged is the edge detected image
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:5]
# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    # if our approximated contour has four points, then we
    # can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx) == 4:
        screenCnt = approx
        break
```

In the above snippet, first it finds the contours from a edge detected image, then it sorts the contours to find the five largest contours. Finally it loop over the contours and used `cv2.approxPolyDP` function to smooth and approximate the quadrilateral. `cv2.approxPolyDP` works for the cases where there are sharp edges in the contours like a document boundary.

Comment: Thank You.
and how cv2.arcLength() works.
I know definition.Wanted to know why it is being used and how it works(I saw on internet but didn't get it).

Comment: ```cv2.arcLength()``` is used to calculate the perimeter of the contour. If the second argument is ```True``` then it considers the contour to be closed. Then this perimeter is used to calculate the epsilon value for ```cv2.approxPolyDP()``` function with a precision factor for approximating a shape. You can look into the link: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html where it is explained. There is also a link to the wiki for Douglas-Peucker algorithm behind cv2.approxPolyDP() method.